# Internal server error http 500 wamp and codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, wamp

Can't get my site to run local with wamp and are out of options on what to do.

I can access `phpmyadmin` but not the site.

New fresh version of wamp installed.
`Rewritemodule` is enabled.
I added `require all granted` in httpd.conf

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Comment: Please check the apache error log and let me know what is there in the error log when you try the request.